# pydev on eclipse: does not appear new python project

Tags: python, eclipse, ubuntu, pydev

I'm running ubuntu 16.10 and eclipse 3.8, I've installed PyDev following this guide: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html

The plugin seems installed looking at the 'installed software' tab.

```
java -version 

java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

I do not understand why I do not see 'python project' in the 'new project' tab.

Comment: So did you install  PyDev 4.5.5 as that page says is required for Eclipse 3.8?

Comment: oh no! i had the newer version, now it's working.